# How can move content bottom of AlertDialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to display some option in the bottom of Flutter AlertDialog. As you can see

[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I'm trying AlertDialog but it's showing content in the center of Device. I want to move it bottom and change background as transparent.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you can use the [showDialog](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/showDialog.html) component which lays behind the AlertDialog with a nested Column. For a greyed out background ou can use [Opacity](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) with a Container:

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
       return Opacity(
          opacity: 0.8, // some opacity
          child: Container(
              // container to set color
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: null,
                    ), // replace with your buttons
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: null,
                    ),
                  ]
               )
            )
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: still the background not transparent

Comment: Well then you could use an `Opacity` Widget with a `Container`, see the updated example.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way: you can use padding

```
showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:300.0),
            child: //AlertDiloag / CupertinoAlertDialog
          );
        },
      );
```